# Connect to Orange interface in IPCop

Tags: firewall, linux-networking, ipcop

I am using IPCop with a red-green-orange configuration.  I am trying to access my webserver on the orange interface, from a computer on the green interface, both of which are inside my firewall.

When I enter the IP address of the webserver, I reach that machine and it does serve up a page, but the page is missing all of the CSS and JS goodies.  It seems like only a bare, minimal version of the page is loading.

Is there something I am doing wrong?  I would like to be able to access the default website on the webserver and have all of the CSS and JS load as well.  I don't know why I am getting only the minimal version of the site being served up.

Any ideas?  Thank you.